# Remote Debugging an Aarch64 ELF File on Multiarch/Qemu-user-static (arm64v8/alpine) Docker Container

Tags: debugging, gdb, remote, aarch64

My goal is stated in the title. However, I think there is a fundamental issue with gdbserver. In particular, I create an aarch64 alpine docker container on a x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04 host using

`sudo docker run --rm -it -p 12345:12345 -v /host_dir:/container_dir --privileged arm64v8/alpine /bin/ash`

I then proceed to install `gdb` in the container using `apk add gdb`. Subsequently I run `ps aux` just to get a list of the processes running in the container in order to test `gdbserver --attach COMM...PID` command in the container. Interestingly absolutely no output no matter how much time goes on. As a result, I switch to the host and simply do the same exercise on the Ubuntu machine, i.e., I attach to a random process with `pid` 23056. The output to `gdbserver --attach :12344 23056` is `Attached; pid = 23056 Listening on port 12344`, which is what I expected to happen with gdbserver in the container. Any help as to why `gdbserver` in the container doesn't behave properly is appreciated!

**EDIT 1:**

I tried again and first ran `sudo docker run --rm -it --privileged -p 7777:7777 -v home_dir:container_dir arm64v8/alpine` and then ran `gdbserver localhost:7777 ./binary` and then as suggested in the comments I used `netstat -l` in the container and got `tcp 0      0 0.0.0.0:7777            0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN`. So it seems that clearly `gdbserver` is listening for a `tcp` connection. Then I use `gdb-multiarch binary` on the host machine and then `(gdb) target remote localhost:7777` to get:

`Remote debugging using localhost:7777`

`Ignoring packet error, continuing...`

`warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response`

`Ignoring packet error, continuing...`

`Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout`

Any idea?!

**EDIT 2:**

I ran the docker container without the `--publish` or `-p` attribute and clearly no matter what `IP:PORT` I use, `gdb-multiarch` says the `Connection timed out`.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is indeed not listening on the port? I seem to recall not always having output. Have you tried debugging the debugger? Maybe try `strace` on `gdbserver`?

Comment: @multithr3at3d Thank you for the comment. Did you also run gdbserver in a docker? As my name says, I'm a newbie and I haven't yet made sure that in fact it is listening or not. I'm thinking maybe I set the docker wrong or I'm just not passing the correct `IP:PORT` to the `target remote` command of `gdb-multiarch` to connect to `gdbserver`. Basically, I don't feel sure about the connection between the container and the host. Can you comment on that. Also, do you see anything wrong with the docker command?

Comment: Haven't used it in Docker, no. In the container, try `ss` or `netstat` with `-l` to see if it's listening on that port. What args are you passing to `target remote`?

Comment: So this is what I just did inside the docker: `gdbserver :7778 binary` and in another terminal (still in container) I did `netstat -l` and I got `Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State`: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7778            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`. So I guess gdbserver is actually listening! On the host I have `gdb-multiarch binary` and then `(gdb) target remote localhost:7778` and after a few seconds I get `localhost:7778: Connection timed out.` It seems that I have the connection between the host and the docker messed up! Right?

Comment: Well that's good news! Are there firewall rules that would block inbound connections to loopback? Alternatively, if you don't use `--privileged`, you could maybe specify the address of the container itself.

Comment: @multithr3at3d So this is from the docker documentation: By default, when you create or run a container using `docker create` or `docker run`, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the `--publish` or `-p` flag. So does this mean that if I don't publish ports there is no means for a TCP connection between the host and the container?

Comment: @multithr3at3d Though I guess if the docker IP is different from the loopback, the issue is `localhost`, right?

Comment: @multithr3at3d I'm gonna add an edit to the question, issue not fixed yet but clearly a different output!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116904/discussion-between-multithr3at3d-and-newbie).

Comment: @multithr3at3d There!